# Can we set horizontal scrollbar for wxcombobox?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

After setting limited width size,strings which is too long get truncated in the dropdown of wxcombobox.

`self.namelist = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, "", size=(270,-1))`

Is there any way to make the combobox dropdown scrolls horizontally.So that we can see long strings.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can use `wx.combo.ComboCtrl` instead which lets you implement the drop-down window yourself, and then you can make it do whatever you want.  It's not a perfect emulation of the `wx.ComboBox`, and fairly complex compared to the `wx.ComboBox`, so it may not be worth it to you for just adding horizontal scrolling.  You can see examples in the wxPython demo.

Comment: Thank you so much RobinDunn.

Comment: Instead of horizontal scroll bar ,can we give tooltip for each items in the dropdown?